# Use automapper to map nested collections of objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I found this link on Github which shows how to set up a mapper configuration when an inner map is nested within an outer one.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings

However this isn't working for me probably as I have a bit of a difference: My `Inner` object is actually a `Collection` of `InnerSource`,

i.e.

```
public class OuterSource
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Collection<InnerSource> Inners { get; set; }
}

public class InnerSource
{
    public int OtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class OuterDest
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Collection<InnerDest> Inners { get; set; }
}

public class InnerDest
{
    public int OtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

The solution in the link gives this code to create the MapperConfiguration

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>();
    cfg.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerDest>();
});

// setup object data

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var dest = mapper.Map<OuterSource, OuterDest>(source);
```

But then when I run this, I get an AutoMapperMappingException 
(Inner Exception = 
`Argument 'value' must not be null.
Parameter name: value` )

How can I create a nested mapping like this but where the inner object is a Collection? Note my real case is a bit more complex than the code provided above (with several `.ForMember()` calls)

Comment: This should work, we use mappings similar to this. Did you tried some other Type like `ICollection<>`, `IList<>` or `List<>` instead?

Comment: You need to correct your [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because I tried your code with `AutoMapper 5.1.1` and it's working fine. Most likely your configuration for one of the members is incorrect.

Comment: Did you initialize the 'Inners' collection on `source` when you ran your code?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider, tried it on provided code - `AutoMapper` is setting `dest.Inners` to empty collection. OP needs to provide more info on map configuration.

Comment: working fine on my end, too (with and without an instantiated inner collection